# Rails 3.2 broke my cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I upgraded to Rails 3.2.0 from Rails 3.1.3. All my tests were running nicely until I upgraded, then I get this error when starting 'rake cucumber'

```
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "accounts_id_seq" for serial column "accounts.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "accounts_pkey" for table "accounts"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "employees_id_seq" for serial column "employees.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "employees_pkey" for table "employees"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "entities_id_seq" for serial column "entities.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "entities_pkey" for table "entities"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "folios_id_seq" for serial column "folios.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "folios_pkey" for table "folios"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "ledger_defaults_id_seq" for serial column "ledger_defaults.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "ledger_defaults_pkey" for table "ledger_defaults"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "ledgers_id_seq" for serial column "ledgers.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "ledgers_pkey" for table "ledgers"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "staff_id_seq" for serial column "staff.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "staff_pkey" for table "staff"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "transactions_id_seq" for serial column "transactions.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "transactions_pkey" for table "transactions"
/home/map7/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby -S bundle exec cucumber  --profile default
Using the default profile...

[DEVISE] Devise.case_insensitive_keys is false which is no longer supported. If you want to continue running on this mode, please ensure you are not using validatable (you can copy the validations directly to your model) and set case_insensitive_keys to an empty array.


[DEVISE] Devise.use_salt_as_remember_token is false which is no longer supported. Devise now only uses the salt as remember token and the remember_token column can be removed from your models.


[DEVISE] Devise.reset_password_within is nil. Please set this value to an interval (for example, 6.hours) and add a reset_password_sent_at field to your Devise models (if they don't have one already).

cannot load such file -- cucumber/web/tableish (LoadError)
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/map7/pais/features/support/env.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:129:in `load'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:129:in `load_code_file'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:171:in `load_file'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:174:in `load_step_definitions'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:40:in `run!'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/bin/cucumber:19:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/home/map7/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/r...]

Tasks: TOP => cucumber => cucumber:ok
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remarked out the following in env.rb

```
#require 'cucumber/web/tableish'
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like tableish method deprecated in recent version...

Here I have fixed issue by removing following line

```
#require 'cucumber/web/tableish'
```

in features/support/env.rb

It works for me.